# add fields to edmx after update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a procedure with and old object context ef data model that I converted to tt and object context.

At this point I have a thing to do: with old version of ef data model wizard, finding a field in a table with a foreign key reference, in the data model was added just the navigation property, and not the field property. This behavior has been changed in ef 4, adding but, but this model is done with first ef version, and I would like to fix it.
  How can add the field properties in this existing model?

Luca

Comment: have you tried updating your mode from model browser?

Comment: when I open the model I see no changes and even adding new tables the existing ones are not updated

Comment: can you simply create a new model based on your database?

Comment: I would like to avoid this because I have a lot of tables on it, and I have done a lot of refactoring and renaming. Recreate this means redo this from scratch

Comment: I've faced this problem as well some time ago. And I also had navigation properties renamed, because names like `Person1` and `Person2` were of no use. I've adjusted my t4 template later to name those properties based on FK information so that every time I generate the model properties are named the same unique way. You may want to install newer version of EFTools and quite possible that update of model will work with those tools installed.

Comment: hmmm ... done several changes, debug the changes in t4 template seems more complicated than redo it from scratch

Comment: Did you select the checkbox create foreign keys when you did the upgrade? If not or you are not sure open the Edmx file with an XML editor of your favor and search and delete the navigation property and the field from both schemes, after this update your model again and make sure you checkbox saying generate foreign keys.